# Can I set up a condition in XSL/XML for media type?

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

I am working on a navigation that is set up using XML.

Yes, I know it's not ideal. No, it's not negotiable with the business owner.

I am trying to establish a responsive global navigation that will serve up one version of the navigation for mobile, and one for traditional devices.

Basically, the goal is to not have the mobile nav show up just because the screen gets resized

Can I set up a condition in the xsl to pull one or the other, or use the XSL/XML to detect media type?

I know, this is far from the best set up, but these are the boundaries I have to work in.

TIA

Comment: By "detect" I assume you mean you need to determine the web browser as the page is visited. If that is the case then the answer is no, you need Javascript or CSS with media queries for that. If you know the browser size ahead of time and it's in the XML then sure you could probably do this. Either way, you need to update your question with some example of what I've tried in order to get a clear answer from anyone.

Comment: **"these are the boundaries I have to work in" isn't a good excuse.** If your client is asking unreasonable things, its your job, duty even, to push back and offer a feasible solution.